# mgjava.jar invalid zip file, org.eclipse.jdt.core

Tags: java, eclipse

I am on a Macbook Pro(10.9.5). I have Java 8 installed. I just installed eclipse 4.4.1.

I'm trying to compile my first 'helloworld' app. Regardless if I use eclipse or build with a text editor and compile from the command line, I get an error related to:

```
 /Users/myname/Library/Java/Extensions/mgjava.jar
```

In eclipse it says its an invalid zip file. From a command prompt, when I attempt to compile, I get:

```
 error: error reading /Users/myname/Library/Java/Extensions/mgjava.jar; error in opening zip file
```

The file itself is not new, it from 2013. So I'm guessing I have an old file that needs to be updated, but I have not the foggiest idea how. I google quite a bit, and could find no mention of that specific file.

I have 3 version of Java installed:

```
 1.8.0_161, x86_64: "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-462, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-462, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Any insights?

Comment: I give up: what's `mgjava.jar`? Because you should redownload it. Or delete it. What does it have to do with a helloworld app?

Comment: I have no idea! I can't find mention of it on google. I've never done development work with java before, so no idea how it got there.

Comment: Apparently it's "Autodesk Mapguide" - and it's broken in new versions of Java. Delete it. Unless you do a lot of GIS/mapping work. In which case contact your IT department.

Comment: That resolved the issue! Thank you Elliot!